# Symfony4 is there any way to get my Domain Name?

Tags: php, symfony, dns, symfony4

I know i can get a lot of informations about the HTTP request by doing $request->getSomething, but I didn't find anything anywhere to get my domain name.

I need it for mailing, when i click on links in mails `<a href="{{ path('lesseeRegistration', {'invitationToken': invitationToken}) }}" target="_blank">ici</a>`, I'm redirected to http://myRoute, and I want to be redirect to http://myDomainName/myRoute. Of course I could cheat by writting staticly my domain name, but I would like solve my problem by a better way

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to get an absolute URL. There is a twig function `url`. [Doc here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#url)

You use it like the `path` function:

```
<a href="{{ url('lesseeRegistration', {'invitationToken': invitationToken}) }}" target="_blank">ici</a>
```